# How do I write the makefile for a kernel module in OpenWrt to load the module automatically

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, openwrt

I'm writing a simple kernel module for Openwrt. I have working code that loads and does what it needs to do. What I am missing is how to get the code into the build process of Openwrt. I have a Makefile as below:

```
# Copyright (C) 2006-2012 OpenWrt.org
#
# This is free software, licensed under the GNU General Public License v2.
# See /LICENSE for more information.

include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/kernel.mk

# name
PKG_NAME:=HelloWorld
# version of what we are downloading
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
# version of this makefile
PKG_RELEASE:=0

PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)
PKG_CHECK_FORMAT_SECURITY:=0

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define KernelPackage/$(PKG_NAME)
    SUBMENU:=Other modules
    TITLE:=helloworld lkm
    FILES:= $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/hello.ko
endef

define KernelPackage/$(PKG_NAME)/description
    A sample kernel module.
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef

MAKE_OPTS:= \
    ARCH="$(LINUX_KARCH)" \
    CROSS_COMPILE="$(TARGET_CROSS)" \
    SUBDIRS="$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)"

define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C "$(LINUX_DIR)" \
        $(MAKE_OPTS) \
        modules
endef

$(eval $(call KernelPackage,$(PKG_NAME)))
```

I'm trying to follow the instructions here: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages#creating_packages_for_kernel_modules

Right now, I can see the module in the make menuconfig and select it. However when I run the build in QEMU I don't see the module. I can actually copy the *.ko module over and load it and that works. I just want the module to load automatically. How can I do that?

Comment: You use slightly wrong terminology to describe what you want to achieve. If I understand the question the problem is in creating an image which contains the kernel module. Easiest way is just to build in one.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the function for installing your module. Check in the build or tmp dir. I'm guessing that it's being built but not included in the final image.

Comment: @LucasRamage I think this is the problem. Now what function do I use to install the module? I don't see that in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

In `Build/Compile`, you need a line to include your module.

`define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C "$(LINUX_DIR)" \
        $(MAKE_OPTS) \
        CONFIG_<your mod>=m \ # THIS LINE IS MISSING
        modules
endef`

This are some good examples in the tree. Check out [exfat-nofuse](https://github.com/openwrt/packages/blob/5dd0a570e6941a0dcc51aafed767141276851956/kernel/exfat-nofuse/Makefile).